# Parsing Numeric Values with Java's Regular Expression Classes

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I'm attempting to parse data from an ASCII output file. A sample of the data looks is show below. The values are formatted precision 5 scale 3 and no space exists between the values.

80.234 *<- 1 value*
71.01663.129 <- *2 values ...*
67.09159.25353.997
56.02759.77859.25057.749
55.86558.46958.64861.72855.969

What regular expression pattern can I use to match the number values and split them into groups? The pattern (\d+.\d{1,3}) matches a single value. However, with the number of groups for the line specified it does not give the expected answer. For example, I expected the following to find 10 groups.

```
String testPattern = "68.65761.25659.01057.67657.14857.06457.41658.77861.16268.641";

// create a pattern to match the output
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d{1,3}){10}");

Matcher m = p.matcher(testPattern);

if (m.find())
{
    String group = m.group();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting it to somehow break out the individual numbers because that's how you matched them, but it doesn't work that way.  What your regex does is capture one number at a time and place it into group #1.  Ten times it does this, each time overwriting the contents of group #1 with the new value.  When it's done, `group()` returns the whole string as you discovered, while `group(1)` would return only the tenth number, `68.641`.

This is a common error, probably due to Java's lack of a built-in "find all matches" mechanism.  .NET has its `Matches()` methods, PHP has `preg_match_all()`, Python has `re.findall()`, Perl and JavaScript have the `/g` modifier... every major flavor has a mechanism to return either an array of all matches or an iterator over the matches, or both.  But in Java you're expected to call `find()` in a `while` loop, as @KennyTM demonstrated.

It's an annoying omission, but not really a surprising one, for Java.  Its effect is to force us to write more verbose, less idiomatic code, which has been a Java hallmark from the very beginning.  But if you really want to reduce this task to a one-liner, there's the old "split on a lookaround" trick:

```
String[] result = source.split("(?=\\B\\d{2}\\.\\d{3})");
```

...or:

```
String[] result = source.split("(?<=\\G\\d{2}\\.\\d{3})");
```

Answer (score 4):

If they're all identically formatted, perhaps it would be easier to just read in 6 characters as a string, then use Double.parseDouble to parse that from string to Double?

Answer (score 2):

There is only 1 group with your regex. Use a `while` loop to enumerate all of them. (See http://www.ideone.com/FNRsz):

```
String testPattern = "68.65761.25659.01057.67657.14857.06457.41658.77861.16268.641";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d{1,3}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(testPattern);

while(m.find())   // <---
   System.out.println(m.group());
```

Comment: This will work, even though his regexp is wrong.  I'm guessing that it should be "\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\d".  The variable length matching groups on both ends only work because the numbers are always at maximum length, so greediness does the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), a fixed-length [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) would work well here.

```
Iterable<String> numbers = Splitter.fixedLength(6).split(testPattern);
```

If you were to create a `Function<String, Double>` (called, say, `Numbers.doubleParser()`), you could even convert the data to numbers easily. (Obviously you could use `BigDecimal` or whatever rather than `Double` depending on your needs.)

```
private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.fixedLength(6);

...

public void someMethod(String stringToParse) {
  for(Double value : Iterables.transform(SPLITTER.split(stringToParse),
                                         Numbers.doubleParser())) {
    ...
  }
}
```